# Installation of iPad App immediately followed by Update?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an iPad App that is 51.87MB in size.  I am trying to configure it so that users can install version 1.1.  Right now, the user must download version 1.0, and wait for the update to appear in the App Update Store so that the user can download and update to Version 1.1.

Is there a way to set this up so that the user can download the newest version directly, or is there only an upgrade option?  Is the user going to have to do 3 downloads and installations if I do another update?  Is the size of the application an issue in this process?

Thank You...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once version 1.1 is available in the App Store, users who already have version 1.0 on their device should be able to update to version 1.1, and users who are downloading the app for the first time (or re-downloading it after deleting) will only be able to download version 1.1.

The same applies to any future version: existing users can update; new users can only download the latest version.